# Concatenate comma separated strings using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a utility function that concatenates a few parameters comma-separated to a `formattedString`

```
const formattedString = StringHelper.format(
  '{0},{1},{2},{3}',
  address.Street || '',
  address.City || '',
  address.State || '',
  address.CountryOrRegion || ''
);
```

The StringHelper.format functions looks like this. I wouldn't like to modify this function and would like to use it as a black-box.

```
export function format(template: string, ...values: any[]): string {
 return template.replace(FORMAT_REGEX, (match: string, valueIndex: string) => {
 const value = values[Number(valueIndex)];

 return value === null ? '' : `${value}`;
});
}
```

However, if one of these parameters, say the Street is not present, it looks like `,City1,State1,CountryOrRegion1`. I would like it to look as `City1,State1,CountryOrRegion1` instead.

Is there a way I can specify a regex to allow for this?

A more naive way might to be push to an array and join after passing through a filter.

```
let addressDetails: string[] = [];
addressDetails.push(address.Street, address.City, address.State, address.CountryOrRegion);
formattedString = addressDetails.filter(Boolean).join(',');
```

Comment: But your template has three commas (`'{0},{1},{2},{3}'`), so by which logic will you remove one? What if the template would have looked like `'{0} is a street in {1}, the city in {2} of {3}, you know!?'`... how would you decide what fixed text to remove when one of the arguments is absent?

Comment: @trincot nice point! But at this point, I'm just going to assume the template is just comma-join-everything. I'd like to skip concatenating if not present.

Comment: But that means you will dynamically change the template and remove commas... this will be an ugly, not flexible, solution.

Comment: @trincot, hm, true, doesn't look like the regex can be modified. I'll go with the filter/join solution then. Shall close the question in a few hours just in case someone wants to add.